# different variables in each for loop in C language

Tags: c, for-loop, variables

I want my loop to inlcude different variables every time it starts from beggining. It should be like this:

```
int a1, a2, a3;
...
...
for (i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{
a**i**
}
```

I just want to change variables in loop basing on i which increases by 1 every time.
How to do thing like this?

Comment: What does 'change variables' mean

Comment: Use an array ...

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the 3 `int` variables into an array, and go through all elements of the array in a loop, accessing one element of the array per loop iteration. In every loop iteration, you can do something with the array element, for example print it using `printf`.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    //declare and initialize 3 "int" variables in an array
    int a[3] = { 10, 11, 12 };

    //go through the entire array in a loop, printing one
    //element per loop iteration
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", a[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
10
11
12
```

If you instead want to keep the `3` int variables as separate entities, then you could instead create an array of pointers, where each pointer points to one of these `int` variables, and use that array of pointers in the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    //declare and initialize 3 separate "int" variables
    int a1 = 10, a2 = 11, a3 = 12;

    //create and initialize array of pointers to 
    //these "int" variables
    int *pointers[3] = { &a1, &a2, &a3 };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", *pointers[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program has exactly the same output as the other program.

Comment: is that possible to put variables into array (or their pointers)? for example
```#include <stdio.h> 

int main( void )
{
    int *ptr, *ptr2, b1, b2;
ptr = &b1
ptr2 = &b2
    int a[3] = { ptr, ptr2}; 

    //go through the entire array in a loop, printing one
    //element per loop iteration
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", a[i] );
    } 

    return 0;
}```

Comment: @xantico: I have added a second code example to my answer, which keeps the 3 separate `int` variables, and uses an array of pointers instead. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot <3